# Delete all the records from a table

Tags: database, delphi

How can we delete all the records from a table in DELPHI? we are not allowed to use loop like this:

```
for k:=1 to table1.recordcount do
    begin
      table1.Last;
      table1.Delete;
    end;
```

is there any solutions?

Comment: What kind of table? BDE TTable? ADO Table? dbExpress?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to accomplish it with a SQL database is to perform the delete directly on the server, without moving a client side cursor. Your way you end up to issue several DELETE commands, one for each record, when a single DELETE command can delete all records at once.

Even better, some databases has a TRUNCATE command  (that's Oracle, but there can be an equivalent command for other DBs) that can empty a whole table without generating rollback data, which usually is faster and requires less resources on the server - as long as you are sure you don't need to rollback the command later.

If the database is not a SQL database, the documentation will tell you which is the best way to empty its tables.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a Query component (TQuery or TAdoQuery or TSQLQuery), set its SQL.Text property to `Delete From <TableName>` and then use `Query.ExecSQL` (instead of `Query.Open`).

Answer (score 6):

How about Table1.EmptyTable?

Or, less efficiently:

```
while table1.recordcount <> 0 do
  table1.Delete;
```

Comment: Will this Table1.EmptyTable actually delete the records in the actual database?